# Coefficient of Divergence - how to code loop more efficiently?

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix

I have a matrix of 1500 rows and 20 columns and would like to calculate the Coefficient of Divergence between columns (ie. sites). Each row is my hourly observation per site.

Calculation for COD between two sites is as stated in https://www.scribd.com/document/364585909/Coefficient-of-Divergence-COD

I have created a simpler dataset to work with:

```
x1 <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
x2 <- c(11, 21, 31, 41, 51)
x3 <- c(12, 22, 32, 42, 52)
x4 <- c(13, 23, 33, 43, 53)
x5 <- c(14, 24, 34, 44, 54)
x6 <- c(15, 25, 35, 44, 55)

xmat <- cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)
```

#### first COD

```
site1 <- xmat

for (i in 2:ncol(site1))   

     site1[,i] = (xmat[,i]-xmat[,1])/(xmat[,i]+xmat[,1])
     site1 <- site1[,2:6]
     site1 <- sapply(site1, function(x) x^2)
     COD-site1 <- data.frame(sqrt(colMeans(site1, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

### second COD

```
site2 <- xmat

for (i in 3:ncol(site2))

    site2[,i] = (xmat[,i]-xmat[,2])/(xmat[,i]+xmat[,2])
    site2 <- site2[,3:6]
    site2 <- sapply(site2, function(x) x^2)
    COD-site2 <- data.frame(sqrt(colMeans(site2, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

etc....

I'm having a problem on how to loop through columns and create a new data frame for CODs. In my simple dataset, it's over 6 columns but in my actual dataset, I have 20 columns and don't really want to copy and paste 20 times. I'm a novice in writing function and loop for R and would appreciate a lending hand. Many thanks

Comment: As is, your code does not compile with error at `colMeans`: *'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions*. And R does not use hyphens in names.

Answer (score 1):

With matrix objects, elemetwise operations of same sizes can be handled without loops such as `for` and `sapply` where you can run arithmetic directly on whole objects in vectorized processes:

**Site 1**

```
site1 <- xmat
site1[,2:ncol(site1)] <- (xmat[,2:ncol(site1)]-xmat[,1])/(xmat[,2:ncol(site1)]+xmat[,1])
site1 <- site1[,2:6]^2
COD_site1 <- data.frame(result=sqrt(colMeans(site1, na.rm=TRUE)))
COD_site1
```

**Site 2**

```
site2 <- xmat
site2[,3:ncol(site2)] <- (xmat[,3:ncol(site2)]-xmat[,2])/(xmat[,3:ncol(site2)]+xmat[,2])
site2 <- site2[,3:6]^2
COD_site2 <- data.frame(result=sqrt(colMeans(site2, na.rm=TRUE)))
COD_site2
```

To iterate across, generalize your processing and run in a loop like `lapply` to build a list of return values. Have the loop iterate across the number of columns of original matrix minus first item (i.e., 2, 3, 4, 5, 6):

```
result_list <- lapply(seq(ncol(xmat))[-1], function(i) {

  tryCatch({
     site <- xmat
     site[, i:ncol(site)] <- (xmat[,i:ncol(site)]-xmat[,i-1])/(xmat[,i:ncol(site)]+xmat[,i-1])
     site <- as.matrix(site[,i:ncol(xmat)]^2)
     COD_site <- data.frame(result=sqrt(colMeans(site, na.rm=TRUE)))

     # RETURN LIST OF BOTH ITEMS
     return(list(site, COD_site))

   }, error = function(e) list(NA, NA)
  )

})
```

Even name list elements according to site:

```
names(df_list) <- paste0("COD_site", seq(ncol(xmat)-1))
```

Even extract lists into their own types:

```
mat_lists <- lapply(result_list, `[[`, 1)

df_lists <- lapply(result_list, `[[`, 2)
```

---

**mat_lists**

```
mat_lists
# $COD_site1
#                x2           x3           x4          x5          x6
# [1,] 0.0022675737 0.0082644628 0.0170132325 0.027777778 0.040000000
# [2,] 0.0005948840 0.0022675737 0.0048674959 0.008264463 0.012345679
# [3,] 0.0002687450 0.0010405827 0.0022675737 0.003906250 0.005917160
# [4,] 0.0001524158 0.0005948840 0.0013064305 0.002267574 0.002267574
# [5,] 0.0000980296 0.0003844675 0.0008483363 0.001479290 0.002267574

# $COD_site2
#                x3           x4           x5           x6
# [1,] 8.218953e-05 5.787037e-04 1.728000e-03 3.641329e-03
# [2,] 1.257751e-05 9.391435e-05 2.962963e-04 6.575162e-04
# [3,] 3.999248e-06 3.051758e-05 9.831589e-05 2.226118e-04
# [4,] 1.748903e-06 1.349746e-05 4.396499e-05 4.396499e-05
# [5,] 9.151417e-07 7.111971e-06 2.332362e-05 5.373563e-05

# $COD_site3
#                x4           x5           x6
# [1,] 2.560000e-06 3.501278e-05 1.524158e-04
# [2,] 2.438653e-07 3.573458e-06 1.659945e-05
# [3,] 5.602045e-08 8.432265e-07 4.019627e-06
# [4,] 1.915686e-08 2.925002e-07 2.925002e-07
# [5,] 8.227025e-09 1.267350e-07 6.179451e-07

# $COD_site4
#                x5           x6
# [1,] 6.969172e-08 1.859344e-06
# [2,] 4.360243e-09 1.255867e-07
# [3,] 7.406721e-10 2.200926e-08
# [4,] 2.006336e-10 2.006336e-10
# [5,] 7.129862e-11 2.177866e-09

# $COD_site5
#              [,1]
# [1,] 1.681171e-09
# [2,] 7.224762e-11
# [3,] 9.266281e-12
# [4,] 0.000000e+00
# [5,] 5.962673e-13
```

**df_lists**

```
df_lists
# $COD_site1
#        result
# x2 0.02600634
# x3 0.05010383
# x4 0.07253009
# x5 0.09348300
# x6 0.11206961

# $COD_site2
#         result
# x3 0.004504006
# x4 0.012031168
# x5 0.020927975
# x6 0.030394597

# $COD_site3
#          result
# x4 0.0007599039
# x5 0.0028230728
# x6 0.0058982253

# $COD_site4
#          result
# x5 0.0001225272
# x6 0.0006339273

# $COD_site5
#         result
# 1 1.877915e-05
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. I try lapply to my sample dataset and it works fine however I get the following error message using my big dataset: " Error in Ops.data.frame(hrlymatrix[, i:ncol(site)], hrlymatrix[, i - 1]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames".

Comment: I have some NAs in my big dataset. Are they the culprit?

Comment: Likely it is due to NAs as the `colMeans` removes them. Use `tryCatch` to return NAs for those iterations. See update. Check list output to see which sites are at issue.

Comment: A small edit:  site <- as.matrix(site[,i:ncol(xmat)]^2) on line 6 as it's squared of proportion from previous line.

Ideally I prefer not to replace NAs as they were observations when instrument didn't record on that hour. It happened a lot in the field (due to instrument failure or lost of power, etc). However I get most CODs as NA with the updated code except for one site :(